# How to regain control of goDaddy domain from lost or unreachable admistrator or best way to Reoute traffic

Tags: dns, cross-domain

I have migrated 90% of the needed content from

http://avanzadasa.com/

To this other hosted web site

http://avanzadasa.co/

My brother is the rightfull owner of the brand AVANZADA SA and he does not have access to the GoDaddy account that was used to purchase de domain

What is the fastest way of rerouting all traffic and make root DNS hosts update the IP address to point to the http://avanzadasa.co/

Answer (score 1):

Can you manage the domain http://avanzadasa.com/ or the server of http://avanzadasa.com/. There're few ways to redirect on your new domain:

1. Specify URL dns record on your DNS Control Panel
2. Config your server configuration.
3. Redirect with meta tag
4. Redirect by using Javascript

You can check out full of list here: http://www.wikihow.com/Redirect-a-URL

Comment: Option 4 seems undoable since publishing to the site is not possible and is exactly what we are trying to solve. Thanks for your answer.